# PG full text search on rails using pg_search gem for substring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, pg-search

I am using Pg full text search for my search . As i am using Ruby on rails, I am using pg_search gem. How do i configure it to give a hit for substring as well.

```
pg_search_scope :search_by_detail, 
              :against => [
                   [:first_name,'A'],
                   [:last_name,'B'],
                   [:email,'C']
              ],                  
              :using => {
                :tsearch => {:prefix => true}
              }
```

Right now it gives a hit if the substring is in the start but it wont give a hit if the substring in the middle

example It gives a hit for sdate@example.com but not for example.com

Answer (score 7):

I'm the author and maintainer of pg_search.

Unfortunately, PostgreSQL's tsearch by default doesn't split up email addresses and allow you to match against parts. It might work if you turned on `:trigram` search, though, since it matches arbitrary sub-strings that appear anywhere in the searchable text.

```
pg_search_scope :search_by_detail,
                :against => [
                  [:first_name,'A'],
                  [:last_name,'B'],
                  [:email,'C']
                ],
                :using => {
                  :tsearch => {:prefix => true},
                  :trigram => {}
                }
```

I confirmed this by running the following command in psql:

```
grant=# SELECT plainto_tsquery('example.com') @@ to_tsvector('english', 'name@example.com');
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

I know that the parser does detect email addresses, so I think it must be possible. But it would involve building a [text search dictionary](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html) in PostgreSQL that would properly split the email address up into tokens.

Here is evidence that the text search parser knows that it is an email address:

```
grant=# SELECT ts_debug('english', 'name@example.com');
                                  ts_debug                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (email,"Email address",name@example.com,{simple},simple,{name@example.com})
(1 row)
```

Comment: But what if I need to find text `title` in string `some long subtitle string`?

Comment: I think you should try out some test scenarios. When it comes to pg_search, you're limited by what PostgreSQL can do, and it's best to experiment and see what works best for your use case.

For `title` to match `subtitle`, you would need to match by `:trigram`.