# pg_search email address for substring

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, full-text-search, pg-search, trigram

I'm using pg_search to full_text_search my customer d/b on name and email address. How do I get a match if I search on the domain part of the email address? e.g. hotmail, returns all customers with a hotmail address.

The steps I've taken so far include using trigram search and adding the psql extension for trigram search. The comment in this article, [PG full text search on rails using pg_search gem for substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653301/pg-full-text-search-on-rails-using-pg-search-gem-for-substring) indicates I need to build a text search dictionary. Anyone know how to do that to split up the email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you just be able to search "hotmail" on the email string? pg_search returns results that match a sub-string, so the regular setup will work just fine.

Comment: That is indeed the case. Whilst the functionality was working, my test was failing. I've changed the trigram threshold to 0.2 (the default is 0.3)  and now my test passes.

Comment: What is the syntax for changing threshold in pg_search rails? Thanks