# Weird behaviour with postgresql tsvector and tsquery around emails

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

I've been playing around with postgresqls text search capability and I've encountered what I consider weird behaviour.  This is on postgresql 8.3 so it may not be current behaviour:

```
select to_tsvector('some@email.com') @@ to_tsquery('some@email.com:*');
select to_tsvector('some@email.com') @@ to_tsquery('some@email.c:*');
```

The first query matches but the second fails...

does anyone know what is going on here?

I've tried escaping the @ and . characters but no luck

Comment: Just to further narrow down the weirdness:

`select to_tsquery('english', 'some@email.com:*'), to_tsquery('english', 'some@email.co:*'), to_tsquery('english', 'some@email.c:*') ; `

Comment: This provides a little more detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653301/pg-full-text-search-on-rails-using-pg-search-gem-for-substring